# Did I miss anything on this question about continuity on the value of $\alpha$

Tags: calculus, continuity

For what value of $\alpha$ is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x = 1$ For each of those values of $\alpha$, find $f^{\prime}(1)$

$$\mbox{Let }  f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x-4\tan (x) & x \leq 0 \\ x^{\alpha} + x^2 & 0 < x < 1 \\ 9x-8 & x \geq 1 \end{cases} $$

To be differentiable, it must be continuous at $x=1$

Thus $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}} x^{\alpha} + x^2 = \lim\limits_{x\to 1^{+}} 9x-8$ 
The right hand side limit is 1.

Thus $f(x)$ is continuous when $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}} x^{\alpha} + x^2 = 1$

doing direct substitution for $x=1$ in the limit in question, gives $1^{\alpha} + 1^2 = 1$ which means if $\alpha = 0$ then it is continuous. **made a mistake**

I also know that $f^{\prime}(1) = 9$.

I have only found one value of $\alpha$, the question implies there are others.

**Are there other values for $\alpha$ for which $f(x)$ is continuous?**

Edit.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}} x^{\alpha} + x^2 = 
\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}} x^{\alpha} + \lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}} x^2 = 1^{\alpha} + 1 $$

and one raised to anything is one, thus $f(x)$ is not continuous at one, therefore can not be differentiable at $x=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1^0 = 1$, i.e., $1^0 + 1^2 \neq 1$. Also, continuity is not  sufficient for differentiability. Consider for example $f(x) = |x|$, which is continuous but not differentiable at $x=0$.

You may consider the following
$$\lim_{x \nearrow 1} x^{\infty} = 0.$$

Comment: Yes that is correct.  Thus it is never continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: I suggested that for $\alpha = \infty$ the left and right derivative both equal 1. That is, $$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}} x^{\alpha} + x^2 = 1 = \lim\limits_{x\to 1^{+}} 9x-8$$

Comment: Um, I just check on wolfram alpha and got undetermined, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+x^%28infinity%29%2Bx^2+as+x+to+1+from+the+left

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The function is continuous at $x=1$ for $\alpha = \infty$, not differentiable. See http://tinyurl.com/p3utt6x.

Comment: Thanks, I know know how to plot piecewise functions on wolframalpha.